# не работает код на sbcl библиотека cl-glut

Tags: lisp, glut, common-lisp

Пробую освоить библиотеку cl-glut нашел образец кода который должен отобразить хоть какое то окно

```
(defpackage :simple-glut-example
  (: :cl :cl-glut))

(in-package :simple-glut-example)

(defun display ()
  (gl:clear-color 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0)
  (gl:clear :color-buffer-bit)
  (gl:flush))

(defun reshape (width height) 
  (gl:viewport 0 0 width height))

(glut:display-func 'display)
(glut:reshape-func 'reshape)

(glut:init)
(glut:init-display-mode 'double :rgb)
(glut:init-window-size 500 500)
(glut:create-window "Simple GLUT Example")

(glut:main-loop)
```

Comment: Очень мало знаком с lisp, но посмотрите, в строке `(: :cl :cl-glut)` возможно ошибка. Вероятно, должно быть что-то вроде `(:use :cl-glut)` или `(:use #:cl-glut)`  или `:depends-on :cl-glut` чтобы указать зависимость от пакета **cl-glut**.